# Python - CSV transpose cells with the same value / remove duplicates but keep values

Tags: python, csv

I have CSV file:

```
id1,    id2,    value
2.1,    53.2,   0
2.1,    53.2,   1
2.1,    53.2,   3
2.1,    53.2,   8
3.3,    52.5,   0
3.3,    52.5,   6
3.3,    52.5,   9
3.3,    52.5,   12
```

What I want to do is:

1. Concatenate id1+id2 to form unique key - '2.1 53.2'
2. I want to add all values for these keys to that key

Resulting CSV

```
id        val1 val2 val3 val4
2.1 53.2, 0,   1,   3,   8
3.3 52.5, 0,   6,   9,   12
```

After 6h of coding I decided to ask... I used dicReader csvReader etc... I tried to load it into the list, using sets but nothing works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend creating a `defaultdict` to store each entry with a `list` for a value, containing a `value` cell for each matching row. Create the header row by finding the maximum length of these `list`s of `value`s, then iterate over the dictionary and write each entry as a row:

```
import csv
import collections
with open('in.csv', newline='') as f, open('out.csv', newline='') as result:
    next(f) # skip the input header row
    vals = collections.defaultdict(list) # start a default dict of {item:[],...}
    for row in csv.reader(f): # iterate through input CSV
        # find or create the key e.g. "2.1 53.2", and
        # append the id to its list of values
        vals['{} {}'.format(*row[:2])].append(row[2])
    # create a header row by adding ['id'] to a list of "valx" strings
    # by finding the maximum list by length, finding its length,
    # iterating over a range of that number,
    # and creating the necessary "valx" strings
    csv.writer(result, dialect='excel').writerow(['id'] + ['val{}'.format(num) for num in range(len(max(vals.values(), key=len)))])
    for k,v in sorted(vals.items()): # iterate over the items in the sorted dictionary
        # create an appropriate list by adding the key and the values, and write it
        csv.writer(result, dialect='excel').writerow([k] + list(v))
```

Comment: This works as specified. Thank you very much. It is very good that it checks for max number of values because I do not know how many values are going to be returned. I work with file as argument from command line, very suitable for this. Also, I am trying to understand this code better. Would it be much trouble to comment the line?

Comment: @WiktorSypniewski - Sure. I've added inline comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('in.csv'), delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
header = next(reader, None) 
data = [(k1.strip()+' '+k2.strip(),v.strip()) for k1,k2,v in reader]
data = dict(((k1, [v for k2,v in data if k1 == k2]) for k1 in set(zip(*data)[0])))
with open('out.csv', 'w') as outfile:
  writer = csv.writer(outfile)
  writer.writerow(['id', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4'])
  for key in sorted(data.keys()):
    writer.writerow([key] + data[key])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but my list does not have set len()